# Smoothness of $l_p$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, smooth-functions

We define the $L_p$ norm of a function $f \in B$ (where $B$ is a Banach space) as $||f||_p = (\int |f(x)|^p dx)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. I'm trying to understand if the functional $\phi_p(f) = ||f||_p^2$ is smooth and satisfies the condition of $\alpha$-smoothness wrt to $||.||_B$ i.e,
for all $g, g' \in B$
$$\phi_p(g) \le \phi_p(g') + (g-g', \delta_{g'} \phi_p)_B + \frac{\alpha}{2}||g-g'||_B^2$$

What are the structures required on $B$ for this to hold? Assume that $B$ is a family of real-valued functions defined on a space $X \subset R^n$. For the smoothness, let's exclude the zero function.

Comment: Using the letter $f$ everywhere utterly confuses the issue. And it is not the squared $L^p$ norm. Please rewrite and clarify of *what* function you want to study smoothness.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have made the edits. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: OK, thanks. And you really did mean the $2/p$ power. What do you know if $p\le 2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, I do mean $2/p$ power. The only thing that I need to check is if it is differentiable everywhere and that the differential is bounded. For $p \le 2$, $||.||_p^2$ is differentiable everywhere so all we need to check is if the differential is bounded on a ball of norm 1 wrt $||.||_B$. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you not saying $B=L^p(X)$? How does your question make sense otherwise?

Comment: Right, at least for the smoothness condition to hold it should at least be a subset of $L^p(X)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin So, is $B \subset L^p(X)$ sufficient to say that $\phi_p$ is smooth for $1<p \le 2$?